# Repeating Startup Messages in Terminal (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04

Whenever I startup my terminal, I get
[repeating messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udThe.png)

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is presumably something that you have added as part of a  [FreeSurfer Setup and Configuration](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/SetupConfiguration_Linux)